# How should I parse a fixed length record file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing

I was wondering if anyone had any advice on parsing a file with fixed length records in Ruby.  The file has several sections, each section has a header, *n* data elements and a footer. For example (This is total nonsense - but has roughly similar content)

```
1923  000-230SomeHeader     0303030 
209231-231992395    MoreData
293894-329899834    SomeData
298342-323423409    OtherData
3     3423942Footer record  9832422
```

Headers, Footers and Data rows each begin with a specific number (1,2 & 3) in this example.

I have looked at http://rubyforge.org/projects/file-formatter/ and it looks good - except that the documentation is light and I can't see how to have *n* data elements.

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Thanks guys - unpack does the job perfectly.  Cheers!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. The [`unpack` method of `string`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000760) could be used to define a pattern of fields as follows :-

```
"209231-231992395    MoreData".unpack('aa5A1A9a4Z*')
```

This returns an array as follows :-

```
["2", "09231", "-", "231992395", "    ", "MoreData"]
```

See [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000760) for a description of the pack/unpack format.

Answer (score 0):

Several options exist as usual.

If you want to do it manually I would suggest something like this:

very pseudo-code:

```
Read file
while lines in file
    handle_line(line) 
end

def handle_line
    type=first_char
    parse_line(type)
end

def parse_line
    split into elements and do_whatever_to_them
end
```

Splitting the line into elements of fixed with can be done with for instance `unpack()`

```
irb(main):001:0> line="1923  000-230SomeHeader     0303030"
=> "1923  000-230SomeHeader     0303030"
irb(main):002:0* list=line.unpack("A1A5A7a15A10") 
=> ["1", "923", "000-230", "SomeHeader     ", "0303030"]
irb(main):003:0>
```

The pattern used for `unpack()` will vary with field lengths on the different kinds of records and the code will depend on wether you want trailing spaces and such. See [unpack reference](http://www.rubycentral.com/book/ref_c_string.html#String.unpack) for details.